# Why QString("FFFFFFFF").toInt(0, 16); returns 0?

Tags: qt, qstring, twos-complement

As you may know, `0xFFFFFFFF` in the Two's Complement representation equals `-1` (for 32 bits). But the following code:

```
qint32 aa = QString("FFFFFFFF").toInt(0, 16);
qDebug()<<aa;
```

prints `0`. The code below:

```
qint32 aa = 0xffffffff;
qDebug()<<aa;
```

prints `-1`!

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#toInt) you can see that `toInt` "Returns 0 if the conversion fails."

Your input does not fit in a signed 32 bit integer, so presumably the conversion fails.

You can verify this by using the `ok`-parameter:

```
bool ok;
qint32 aa = QString("FFFFFFFF").toInt(&ok, 16);
if (ok) qDebug() << aa;
else qDebug() << "Conversion failed!";
```

Comment: I don't understand why *Your input does not fit in a signed 32 bit integer*. Isn't it -1 ?!

Comment: No. `-1` is `-1`. `0xFFFFFFFF` is `4294967295`. Treating this as `-1` would need a rule for handling overflow, such as two's complement, but `QString::toInt` does not have such semantics. `QString::toInt` treats overflow as an error. This makes its behaviour more predictable across architectures, which is important in a cross-platform toolkit :)

Comment: conversion fails missing 0x hex-keyword.

Comment: @SebastianLange What makes you say that? According to the documentation I linked, you have to specify base (radix) `0` for `toInt` to automatically deduce the base from the prefix. Specifying the base as `16` makes `toInt` understand hex whether or not the `0x` prefix is present, so for example `QString("FF").toInt(0, 16)` successfully evaluates to `255`. This is consistent with what I found testing it.

Comment: I did try it too and it failed me, but i did recheck and i saw i forgot to set the base as you did. Conversion works without 0x prefix, so you are right. But still conversion fails me for FFFFFFFF

Answer (score 2):

FFFFFFFF is not an integer format. 0xFFFFFFFF is. And also 0xFFFFFFFF is out of int range. Try use usigned integer. Change the conversion function toInt to toUInit. Here is the code:

```
quint32 aa = QString("0xffffffff").toUInt(0, 16);
quint32 bb = 0xffffffff;
qDebug()<<aa;
qDebug()<<bb;
```

It has been tested on my machine. The output is 4294967295.